# RAID 1 with a Mac - how to avoid formatting one of the drives

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, raid

I have an iMac with an external 2TB HDD. I recently bought a second 2TB HDD in order to build a RAID 1 (mirrored) with the two drives.

The problem is that Disk Utility forces me to create a new RAID set, add both drives to the set and then **format** the whole set (every drive in it) in order to build the set.
I'm doing it this way, first because I have other disks where I can temporary put all the files that were on the 2TB disk, and second because I'm choosing the 256k block size (I'm dealing almost only with large files).

Anyway, if I want to add a third drive to the set in the future, should I repeat the process of dumping the contents of the RAID set, re-format all the drives and then put the contents back in place or there's an easier way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically the only way unless you have one of the older mac pro's with the raid card. if I was you over usb id leave them as stand alone drives.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer since trying to use this RAID set broight me really a lot of problems: several kernel panics (due to the 256k block size for the RAID set) and an annoying Finder problem I described [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102745/finder-closes-and-reopens-over-and-over?noredirect=1#comment120949_102745) (which now seems to be solved)